# problematic '\\+' sequences in generated TeX files

Tags: c++, doxygen

I recently updated Doxygen, and found that latex has become very unhappy with the generated .tex files - many complaints about 'Undefined control sequence'.  These were associated with instances of '\+' inserted seemingly at random into text.  If I just brute force removed all instances of '\+' from the generated .tex files, pdflatex was able to finish successfully, and I got a reasonable looking document.

I then poked around a little in the Doxygen source, and found that util.cpp seemed to be responsible for emitting the '\+' sequence, and that it did so when a boolean called **insideTabbing** was **not** set.  This seemed kind of odd to me, and as an experiment, changed the sense of the test wherever it was performed.  When I run with the modified doxygen, the generated code seems to be fine.

So, is there some setting in my Doxyfile that I failed to use, and which would have prevented the behavior I've been seeing?

Comment: Are you using a non-standard doxygen.sty file by any chance? I ask because the \+ command is defined in that stylesheet file and was only introduced a couple of versions ago.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've joined a project that had an existing doxygen.sty file, and only gave it a cursory examination. I did use 'doxygen -u' to update the style file after I updated doxygen.

Comment: I just generated a style file from scratch, and diff'ed it against my updated version. The differences all seemed reasonable. Is there a particular kind of setting that I should be looking for?

Comment: The command is actually in refman.tex I now see. It looks as follows `\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{\scriptsize$\hookleftarrow$}}{}{}}` So you are probably using a custom header as well, which is missing this new command.

Comment: That sounds like a very good lead. We do have a 'coverpage.tex' that gets incorporated into refman.tex. I'll be able to edit coverpage.tex on Monday, when I go back to work. If it solves the problem, you can turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That did the trick. I undid my change to doxygen, inserted the newcommand into coverpage.tex, and rebuilt. No complaints from pdflatex. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment about defining `newcommand` provided the answer to my problem. In my Doxygen configuration file, **LATEX_HEADER** is given a file name as a value. The contents of that file end up overriding/replacing some of the content that usually gets generated for `refman.tex`. Once I incorporated `\newcommand{\+}{\discretionary{\mbox{\scriptsize$\hookleftarrow$}}{}{}}` into my header file, `pdflatex` was able to run successfully to completion.